# Data output is not the same as inside function

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I am currently having an issue where I am trying to store data in a list (using dataclasses). When I print the data inside the list in the function (PullIncursionData()) it responded with a certain amount of numbers (never the same, not possible due to it's nature). When printing it after it being called to store it's return in a Var it somehow prints only the same number.

I cannot share the numbers, as they update with EVE Online's API, so the only way is to run it locally and read the first list yourself.

The repository is Here: https://github.com/AtherActive/EVEAPI-Demo

- Heads up! Inside the main.py (the file with issues) (a snippet of code is down below) are more functions. All functions from line 90 and forward are important, the rest can be ignored for this question, as they do not interact with the other functions.

---

```
def PullIncursionData():
    #Pulls data from URL and converts it into JSON
    url = 'https://esi.evetech.net/latest/incursions/?datasource=tranquility'
    data = rq.get(url)
    jsData = data.json()

    #Init var to store incursions
    incursions = []

    #Set lenght for loop. yay
    length = len(jsData)

    # Every loop incursion data will be read by __parseIncursionData(). It then gets added to var Incursions.
    for i in range(length):
        # Add data to var Incursion.
        incursions.append(__parseIncursionData(jsData, i))
        
        # If Dev mode, print some debug. Can be toggled in settings.py
        if settings.developerMode == 1:
            print(incursions[i].constellation_id)

    return incursions

# Basically parses the input data in a decent manner. No comments needed really.
def __parseIncursionData(jsData, i):
    icstruct = stru.Incursion

    icstruct.constellation_id = jsData[i]['constellation_id']
    icstruct.constellation_name = 'none'
    icstruct.staging = jsData[i]['staging_solar_system_id']
    icstruct.region_name = ResolveSystemNames(icstruct.constellation_id, 'con-reg')
    icstruct.status = jsData[i]['state']
    icstruct.systems_id = jsData[i]['infested_solar_systems']
    icstruct.systems_names = ResolveSystemNames(jsData[i]['infested_solar_systems'], 'system')

    return icstruct
    
# Resolves names for systems, regions and constellations. Still WIP.
def ResolveSystemNames(id, mode='constellation'):
    #init value
    output_name = 'none'

    # If constellation, pull data and find region name.
    if mode == 'con-reg':
        url = 'https://www.fuzzwork.co.uk/api/mapdata.php?constellationid={}&format=json'.format(id)
        data = rq.get(url)
        jsData = data.json()
        output_name = jsData[0]['regionname']
    
    # Pulls system name form Fuzzwork.co.uk. 
    elif mode == 'system':
        #Convert output to a list.
        output_name = []
        lenght = len(id)
        # Pulls system name from Fuzzwork. Not that hard.
        for i in range(lenght):
            url = 'https://www.fuzzwork.co.uk/api/mapdata.php?solarsystemid={}&format=json'.format(id[i])
            data = rq.get(url)
            jsData = data.json()

            output_name.append(jsData[i]['solarsystemname'])
    
    return output_name

icdata = PullIncursionData()
print('external data check:')
length = len(icdata)

for i in range(length):
    print(icdata[i].constellation_id)
```

structures.py (custom file)

```
@dataclass
class Incursion:
    constellation_id = int
    constellation_name = str

    staging = int
    staging_name = str

    systems_id = list
    systems_names = list
    region_name = str
    status = str

    def ___init___(self):
        self.constellation_id = -1
        self.constellation_name = 'undefined'

        self.staging = -1
        self.staging_name = 'undefined'

        self.systems_id = []
        self.systems_names = []
        self.region_name = 'undefined'
        self.status = 'unknown'
```

Comment: What is `stru.Incursion`? `__parseIncursionData` is always getting, modifying, and returning that same object. Should that be `icstruct = stru.Incursion()`? It looks like you were forgetting to call the class, and were adding static variables to the class itself. That means `PullIncursionData` was producing a list filled with the same object that was modified over and over again.

Comment: Hello! stru.Incursion is from another file structures.py. I'll add the snippet in here too. My bad!

Comment: If it's a class, then you mean `icstruct = stru.Incursion()`.

Comment: Also in that class, `___init___` should be `__init__` (two underscores). You may just want to get rid of that initializer method and make use of default dataclass `field`s instead though.

Comment: Well, that was a stupid mistake by the looks of it. That was it. Thanks!
The __init__ will be removed yeah. Was aware of the mistake.

Comment: Forgetting to call the class to create an instance is a fairly common error. Usually though, it causes a noticeable failure instead of silently accepting it.

Comment: Yeah I find it odd that it did not give me a heads up, or just fail in the first place.

Comment: Python allows dynamically adding attributes to object (including classes themselves), so you covered up the error by doing the manual `icstruct.constellation_id = jsData[i]['constellation_id']` assignments. Without those assignments, you would have gotten an error later that `AttributeError: type object 'Incursion' has no attribute 'constellation_id'`, which is how the problem typically shows up.